# Angular 5 microservice sso with CAS

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, cas

I am developing an Front end Angular (v5.1.1) app as well as a separate Spring Boot Rest API concurrently.  As for security, the rest api is set up to issue and validate bearer tokens for get and post methods and will eventual reside on an aws server.

The company(school) this app intended for has a separate CAS Server and portal for logging in.  I would like the front end app to redirect to the company's CAS server login page where the user will provide his/her SSO CAS credentials and then redirect back them back to the front end app.  I have used plugins in the past specifically designed for spring boot to accomplish this task (i.e. [Kakawait](https://github.com/kakawait/cas-security-spring-boot-starter).  I have searched to no avail on an example solution that interfaces a modern angular app with CAS just for SSO and void of a custom login page, management server, etc.

My question is how can I quickly implement an Angular app that acts as a CAS client?

Comment: Did your application cross domain? How do you solve it?